# Why are the plural and singular first person forms of the verb "go" so different in the Romance languages?

Tags: etymology, verbs, comparative-linguistics, romance-languages, suppletion

In many Romance languages, the first person plural and singular forms are completely different:

- French (aller): *je vais*, *nous allons*
- Italian (andare): *io vado*, *noi andiamo*
- Catalan (anar): *jo vaig*, *nosaltres anem*

There seems to be something equivalent in [Portuguese](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ir)  and [Gallician](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=ir&Submit=Go&D1=6&H1=106) (but not, surprisingly, in Spanish) and presumably in other Romance languages. The best I could find out for their etymology is that they come from the Latin *ire* which can explain some of the other forms of this irregular verb (*j'irais* for example) but

1. where do these v- and a- forms come from and
2. why are the singular and plural forms so different in so many languages? Do they really come from *ire*?

In short, what's up with this verb?

Comment: This is an example of "suppletion". English also has one of these ("go/went", "be/am/is/are"). Those verbs in Romance languages originate from fusions in conjugated forms of different verbs, namely "ire (to go)", "vadere (to walk)", "alare (Vulgar Latin:to go)".

Comment: @Sindry thanks! I was trying to bring in the Spanish and Italian _andar/e_ but couldn't figure out where it came from. I guess it's also from _alare_. Would that mean the _f-_ forms are from a fourth verb? Any chance of whipping this up into an answer?

Comment: The origin of "andar/e" is still controversal. As for those f- forms, they apparently come from the past forms of "sum (to be)" as you can see in the simple past forms of "be" verbs in other Romance languages. I don't think this is worth whipping up an answer as all the information I posted here is what I got from simplys looking up in Wiktionary except for the name of the phenomenon (suppletion).

Comment: @Sindry fair enough. I checked the Spanish dictionary of the Real Academia and it just said that _ir_ came from _ire_ but no mention of the other forms. Searching Wiktionary didn't occur to me oddly enough.

Comment: Also, Spanish does have mild overlap with *ir/andar* in the *vos* imperative.  Some consider *ir* defective there, but to say "go away", you'd have *vete* (tú), *idos* (vosotros), *váya(n)se* (Vd(s).), but *andate* (vos)

Comment: @Sindry: just a tangential note about "be". There are four roots involved in the conjugation, but they are not "be/am/is/are", but rather "be/is/are/was", with "am" and "is" from the same root, despite appearances to the contrary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller#Etymology) (a source I should perhaps have checked before asking), the *all-* forms ultimately derive from

> Vulgar Latin [*alare*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alare#Latin) (attested in the 7th century [Reichenau Glosses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichenau_Glosses)). This has traditionally been explained as deriving from Latin [*ambulare*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambulare#Latin) via or together with [*ambler*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambler#French) (compare Old Provençal [amblar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amblar#Old_Proven.C3.A7al), Italian [ambiare](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambiare#Italian), Romanian [umbla](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/umbla#Romanian)), but this explanation is phonologically problematic. Several theories have been put forth since the 17th century to explain how ambulare could have become aller.<sup>[[1]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller#cite_note-1)</sup> Since at least the 18th century, some have suggested that aller derives not from Latin but from Celtic<sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichenau_Glosses)</sup>, Gaulish *aliu: compare Welsh [elen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elen#Welsh) (“I was going”), Cornish ellev (“I may go”), and also Franco-Provençal alâ, allar and Friulan [lâ](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A2#Friulian) (“to go”) (compare [lin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lin#Friulian) (“we go”), lât (“gone”)).
>
> Latin [vādō](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vado#Latin) (“go”) supplies the present tense forms and [īre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ire#Latin), present active infinitive of [eō](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eo#Latin), supplies the future and conditional.

As was explained to me by @Sindry, this type of mixed etymology is called [suppletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion), instances of which  are overwhelmingly restricted to the most commonly used lexical items in a language.