# "Go" and "Went" -- how words expressing (to modern speakers) very related concepts sound so different?

Tags: english

Does the difference in sound of these two words in English imply that at one time to "go in the past" was not understood as being related to going in the present? Or that there was no way to express the idea in English so it was borrowed from another language?

I think Mandarin has nothing like this divergence between "go" and "went" and German does not either (could be wrong on German but I think "went" is "gegangen" or something that sounds related to present tense and Mandarin has a very clear and regular way of doing stuff like this.)

Comment: That's called [suppletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) and it's explained well in that Wiki article. Another English example is _be – am, is, are, was, were_ which are all the forms of a single word. Naturally, Mandarin has nothing like that because in Mandarin words don't inflect for any grammar category.

Comment: By the way, German _sein - bin - ist - war_ or _gut - besser_, _viel - mehr_ are examples of suppletion.

Comment: @YellowSky Mandarin does have something like suppletion, in a broader sense; for example, the simple verb negator ‘not’ is 不 _bù_ with all verbs except the verb 有 _yǒu_ ‘have’, where it’s 没 _méi_ instead.

Comment: There were many past forms for 'go' in the dialects of Old and Middle English. The one that finally stuck in Modern English is from the same root as _wend_, replacing the earlier _oede_ or _gang_ forms. Suppletion is a way of life when dialects mix.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That Chinese negator case doesn't fit the idea of suppletion, since 不 bù and 没 méi are not a part of a _paradigm_ in which all the rest of the members are formed by affixes, not by a different morpheme. It doesn't even look like the "lion - lioness, tiger - tigress vs. horse - mare and dog - bitch" stuff. It's more like when everybody say "yes", but in parliament they say "aye". :D

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: mei and bu i remember from first quarter. puzzling.

Comment: @YellowSky Hence why I said something _like_ suppletion. As you say, Chinese cannot have suppletion since there is no such thing as a paradigm, but this is something not too far removed from it. It’s more akin to _do_-support in English, which is also a separate way to form negatives specific to certain verbs, though of course the mechanics are different.

Comment: All Germanic languages have a lot of suppletion in their version of the verb _to be_, including German (_bin/bist_ vs _ist/sind/seid/sein_, _war(en)/wäre(n)/gewesen_, etc.). German also has _gehen_ and _ging/gegangen_, which are suppletive, though they look quite a lot like each other, so many don’t know that they are. Apart from that, I can’t think of any suppletion in German either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "to be" is very abstract and i can see how people struggled with the concepts of various tenses.

Comment: @relesabe Not just tenses – _bin/ist/sind_ are all the same tense, but suppletive.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - German _denken – dachte_ and _bringen – brachte_ look no less suppletive than _gehen – ging_.

Comment: @YellowSky Exactly why most people aren’t aware that _gehen/ging_ is suppletion. Unless you happen to know their etymologies, you really have no way of knowing that they’re not cognate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes suppletion?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28006/what-causes-suppletion)

Comment: @relesabe I think you're mistaken in your apparent belief that suppletion is caused by people "struggling with the concepts of tenses", or struggling with any other grammatical concept for that matter. Languages aren't learned that way anyway, except in school. Suppletion doesn't happen because people fail to grasp their language's structures.

Comment: @LjL: how do we know what causes suppletion?

Comment: @relesabe Suppletion has arisen in languages in recent times and are in fact in the process of arising right now. In English, for example, the singular noun _people_ started to be used as an indefinite plural noun, but it has no direct singular counterpart in that sense. Conversely, as _people_ became more common as a plural noun, the actual plural _persons_ has become less common, to the extent that in unmarked, colloquial speech, _people_ frequently functions as the plural of _person_ – a suppletive paradigm is born, right before our eyes, and not because anyone struggles with ‘persons’.

Comment: As with most language changes, we can identify the direct causes that have the effect observed as a change, but there is no way to know what the underlying reason is. Asking ‘why’ about language structure and language change is usually futile – like asking why English has adjectives or a past tense (there are languages which do fine without both), or why it doesn’t have telicity markers or ergative. It just does/doesn’t.

Comment: The relevant WALS chapter is [79: 'Suppletion According to Tense and Aspect'](https://wals.info/chapter/79). There is also chapter [80: 'Verbal Number and Suppletion'](https://wals.info/chapter/80); both are by Ljuba Veselinova, who knows her stuff. These constitute a large part of her PhD dissertation.

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Etymology Dictionary:](https://www.etymonline.com/)

"The Old English past tense was ***eode***, a word of uncertain origin but evidently once a different verb (perhaps connected to Gothic iddja); it was replaced 1400s by ***went***, past tense of wenden "to direct one's way".

The previous suppletive verb form was considered as confusing because, after reduction, looked like a dental suffix "ed(e)".

The past form of  the synonymous verb ***wend*** was a good solution to this situation.

Comment: Worth noting that this suppletion has caused blocking in Modern English: even though _wend_ (ending in a nasal + voiced stop) still has the right root structure to form a shortened _-t_ past tense (like _spend_ > _spent_), the past tense of _wend_ is now only _wended_ – because obviously _went_ is already taken as the past-tense form of the much more common verb _go_.

Comment: Could OE *eode* be related to Czech, *jít*, *jezdit* etc

Comment: Though we don't know the etymology of the verb, "eode" has some resemblance  with modern Slavonic verbs of the same semantics (for example, Russian JEZDIT', JEDU, etc.).